# consolidate files with unix timestamp folder names write to date folder with single output file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to consolidate folder that has unix timestamp and files(part-00000) and write to single output file in date folder.

Input folder and files :

```
foldername                 filename 
test-f1-1521144092000      part-00000
test-f1-1521141599000      part-00000
test-f1-1521143438000      part-00000
test-f1-1521140713000      part-00000
test-f1-1521204380000      part-00000
test-f1-1521204480000      part-00000
test-f1-1521204490000      part-00000
```

expected output :

```
folder     file
20180315   part-00000
20180316   part-00000
```

Comment: [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and what you still need help with.

Comment: should all grouped `part-00000` files be merged into one?

Comment: yes, all merged into one per date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`bash`** solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in test-f1-[0-9]*/part-00000; do
    d=$(dirname $f)
    d=$(date -d"@${d:8:10}" +'%Y%m%d')
    mkdir -p "$d"
    cat "$f" >> "${d}/part-00000"
done
```